# How to duplicate html divs but each with different data?

Tags: web

Ok. Basically I want to have a div template (e.g. for displaying different people & information - name, picture, information, styling etc.). So is there a way where I can duplicate one template div multiple times to show different data? Would I use JavaScript or a server side script like php pulling from a sql database.
This would also make it easier to exit layer on.
Thanks

Comment: I think something like knockout.js is what you are looking for.

Comment: It depends on where your data comes from, how your web site is built, what you want to achieve... as is, this question seems too broad to me. Can you narrow it down, and provide the code for what you've already tried?

Comment: so client side with something like an ajax call?